# Need help connecting Squirrel SQL Client 4.0.0 to IBM DB2

Tags: java, db2, socketexception, squirrel-sql, invalid-argument

I need help negating this stack trace while trying to connect to the database:

```
java.net.SocketException: Invalid argument: create
    at java.base/java.net.Socket.createImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.x.run(x.java:49)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.a0.a(a0.java:436)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.a0.<init>(a0.java:96)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.a.b(a.java:366)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.b.newAgent_(b.java:2164)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.Connection.initConnection(Connection.java:839)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.Connection.<init>(Connection.java:784)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.b.<init>(b.java:350)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2SimpleDataSource.getConnection(DB2SimpleDataSource.java:233)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2SimpleDataSource.getConnection(DB2SimpleDataSource.java:200)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver.connect(DB2Driver.java:471)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver.connect(DB2Driver.java:113)
    at net.sourceforge.squirrel_sql.fw.sql.SQLDriverManager.getConnection(SQLDriverManager.java:147)
    at net.sourceforge.squirrel_sql.client.mainframe.action.OpenConnectionCommand.executeConnect(OpenConnectionCommand.java:148)
    at net.sourceforge.squirrel_sql.client.mainframe.action.OpenConnectionCommand.lambda$execute$0(OpenConnectionCommand.java:93)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

I've tried googling the best I'm capable of, but cannot figure out what is causing this. Tried changing file/folder permissions to remove any write protection. Tried new drivers from IBM as well, for version 11.5, but same error persists. (With both db2jcc.jar and db2jcc4.jar)

The connection works just fine with an older version of Squirrel, relying on Java 1.7. Version 4.0.0 runs with Java 9, starts just fine, but just won't connect to the database.

Comment: v4.0.0 also works with java 1.8, at least for me on Linux ubuntu 16.04.06

Comment: Running on Windows 10. I'll try changing the Java JRE and see if that does the trick.

Comment: It didn't work with Java JRE 8. Same fault.

Comment: Should it be 32 bit or 64 bit JRE?

Comment: squirrel-sql v4.0.0 works fine for me on Win-10 x64 (1903), with the java 1.8 (64 bit) that is supplied with IBM's Db2 v11.5, connecting to Db2-LUW databases.  I don't have an Oracle jre. You may have some configuration issue.

Comment: In addition, if I install the Oracle 12.0.2 JDK on Win10 x64(1903), the squirrel-sql v4.0.0 seems to work correctly for me with Db2-LUW using the IBM supplied db2jcc4.jar driver. (Currently squirrel-sql v4.0.0 refuses to operate with Oracle Java SE 13, but declares that it supports java 8, 9, 10, 11, 12) at the present date. So your issue is not a general issue, but some local configuration problem.

Comment: Yes, must be some other mysterious issue then. I'll keep investigating.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of September 2019 Db2 for LUW 11.5 [ships with](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/beta/SSEPGG_11.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.qb.server.doc/doc/r0011932.html) and [lists among supported software](https://www.ibm.com/software/reports/compatibility/clarity-reports/report/html/softwareReqsForProduct?deliverableId=171DE660F8D811E8BE8AD213A3013DB3&osPlatforms=Linux&duComponentIds=S001%7CS004%7CS003%7CS014%7CS005%7CA002%7CA007%7CA012) Java 8, which you should take to mean that Java 9 is not officially supported and should not be used.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try changing the Java JRE and see if that works.